# JQuery: How to combine .contains() and .replaceWith()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replacewith

I want to use JQuery to replace the html of and element with my own. I thought I would just be able to use:

```
$('#nav a:contains(replace me)').replaceWith('<h2>Label</h2>');
```

but this does not work. I have tried many variations of this to no avail.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: 
Added current html:

```
<div id="nav">
<a href="#">replace me</a>
<a href="#">this is ok</a>
<a href="#">this is ok</a>
<a href="#">this is ok</a>
</div>
```

What I want it to look like:

```
<div id="nav">
<a href="#"><h2>Label</h2></a>
<a href="#">this is ok</a>
<a href="#">this is ok</a>
<a href="#">this is ok</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the current HTML and what you would like it to look it ?

Comment: Your anchor tags aren't closed properly, but otherwise it seems to be working.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/BDujq/

Comment: @Juhana - not really, as the anchor is removed and replaced with the heading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I'd just do:

```
$('#nav a').html(function(i, html) {
    return $.trim(html) == 'replace me' ? '<h2>Label</h2>' : html;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Au2f2/)

as I'm not very fond of `:contains`, or

```
$('#nav a:contains(replace me)').html('<h2>Label</h2>');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Au2f2/1/)

as `replaceWith()` will replace the entire anchor and not just it's content.

Answer (score 1):

may be it's help for you

```
   $("div").find('a').each(function(index)
    {
        if(index==0){
         $(this).html("<h2>Label</h2>");
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("replace me", "<h2>Label</h2>"); 
});
```

here's a jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/xpfRV/1/